# How to use findstr for multiple strings?

Tags: cmd, findstr

Can someone please help me with this. Is it possible to use findstr in order to find file names that contain 2 different strings, for example.

- I have a folder called New Folder with  3 files called file1, file2 and file3.
- file1 contains words one, two, three, four, five
- file2 contains words one, three, four, five
- file3 contains words two, three, four, five

How do I find the file which contains both "one" and "two", in this case file1. Is this possible to do with findstr or do I have to use grep (which I would like to avoid).

I tried running this command with CMD running in the current directory but I get blank result: `findstr /s /m /c:"one" *.* | findstr /s /m /c:"two"`

I also tried: `for /f %a in ('findstr /s /m "one" "New Folder\*.*"') do @findstr /m "two" %a` but I still get the blank result.

I do not want this as a .bat file but only as CMD command.

Please let me know if this is possible.

```
findstr /s /m /c:"one" *.* | findstr /s /m /c:"two"

for /f %a in ('findstr /s /m "one" "New Folder\*.*"') do @findstr /m "two"
```

Comment: Yes this is possible according to usage help of command __FINDSTR__ output on running `findstr /?` in a command prompt window. The command line to use is: `findstr /M /S /C:one * | findstr /F:/ /M /C:two` The option `/S` on execution of first __FINDSTR__ is only needed on searching in subdirectories should be done too. The list of file names output by first __FINDSTR__ is read by second __FINDSTR__ because of `/F:/` from the console (standard input stream) to search just in these files for the string to find by the second __FINDSTR__.

Comment: I apologize it was my mistake on string values in the files. I have corrected it and your first command works. Thank you!